# My django server does not save my model object but if I use python shell it does

Tags: django, django-models

I'm still learning django, I tried to save an object from my app models on the django server but it does not work, and it shows **OperationalError at/admin** but if I try to use **python shell** to save it, it saves I need help please.

Comment: Please add your code to the question so we can take a look. Also reply to this comment when you've done it so i'll be notified.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello there, can you provide some code so we can help better?
Check the connection to Database in your settings.py and double-check the database server is running.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not specific, but i can guess that you did not maybe execute the migration command to make the auth tables. Try this:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Oh yes, I did that but still didn't work

Comment: I know this may seem trivial, but i am asking just to make sure: you made the migrations (python manage.py makemigrations) before running them, right?